# Execute line of code n times without initializing a variable

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift. I want to add 100 random integers to an array. I have the following working code:

```
var integers = [Int]()

for i in 1...100 {
  integers.append((Int.random(in: 0 ..< 100)))
}
```

The compiler warns me that I did not use `i` inside the scope of the for loop, which is indeed a sensible warning. Is there a way to do some line `n` times without declaring a variable which I won't use anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `i` with `_`.

`_` is just a way of saying that you don't need a variable here. It is known as the "wildcard pattern" in the swift [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html):

> A wildcard pattern matches and ignores any value and consists of an
>   underscore (_). Use a wildcard pattern when you don’t care about the
>   values being matched against. For example, the following code iterates
>   through the closed range 1...3, ignoring the current value of the
>   range on each iteration of the loop:
>
> ```
> for _ in 1...3 {
>     // Do something three times. 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Change `i` to `_`. The use of the underscore is a way to tell the Swift compiler that you don't care about the variable or return value.

You can find this in the Swift book in the Control Flow chapter under [For-In Loops](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID121).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so:

```
let integers = (1...100).map { _ in Int.random(in: 0..<100) }
```